# Have any mechanism like "android service in background execute" in iOS?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, service, background

Can I build a "like android service" APP in iOS?

I have to build a app like android service app( I call gateway APP ),

then the gateway APP will independent exist.

The gateway app will communicate with my other APP(I call B App) and other device( I call A device). The A device have BLE or TCP/IP protocol can send out some data.

Can I build a (like android service app to deal some data transfer) in iOS (I meaning gateway APP)? The gateway APP have to independent exist in iOS background.

Is it probably implement? Have any keyword in gateway App implement method about independent exist?  thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there is no interprocess communication on iOS, so any network operations have to be handled in the main app.

Comment: Sorry, do you know line or hangout how to implement "like service" in background to receive message?  thank you :)

Comment: If use "background Fetch" technology  in iOS7, Can App fetch data communicate with  other app?

Comment: Not really, theres's no effective IPC.